# How to add training algorithm like GradientBoostedTrees in (py)spark into pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a running code with me, but the training model is not the part of pipeline, is there a way to do this here.

Note: char_cols & num_cols are list containing the names of the string & numeric data respectively.

The code below works well

```
string_indexers = [
   StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol="int_{0}".format(x))
   for x in char_cols]

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols= ["int_"+x for x in char_cols] + num_cols,
    outputCol="features"
)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers + [assembler])
features_model = pipeline.fit(df)
indexed = features_model.transform(df)

ml_df = indexed.select(col("OutputVar").cast("int").alias("label"), col("features")).map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features))

gbm = GradientBoostedTrees.trainRegressor(sc.parallelize(ml_df.collect()), categoricalFeaturesInfo={0:24,1:3,2:4,3:5,4:107},  numIterations=3, maxBins=120)
```

but While trying to add even the training model (gbm) in the pipeline for GradientBoostedTrees, there seems no direct way to me.
I need something like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers + [assembler] + [gbm])
```

and the directly do this:

```
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
predictions = model.transform(testData)
```

Though GBTRegressor in pyspark.ml.regression, has inputs like "labelCol" and "featuresCol" which can help us, but for GradientBoostedTrees I find no way for the same. 
Is it possible to pipeline "LabeledPoint" generation step ? or any other help ?

Regards

Comment: Not directly. ML algorithm supports only binary labels not regression.

Comment: @zero323 I did not get you at all. Can you explain it a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to "stages" param:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import GBTRegressor

gr = GBTRegressor()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=string_indexers + [assembler, gr])
```